# Crafter CMS Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, crafter-cms

So i make an update for a template in my crafter authoring studio and published it. Why did when i open the template on crafter delivery the content is not updated in my application. But when i trace into the crafter authoring and delivery VM on path repos, it's already updated (i open the .xml file on repos). From my crafter delivery log i got this error:

Caused by: org.craftercms.search.elasticsearch.exception.ElasticsearchException: [**] Error indexing document /*/*/*/*.xml
at org.craftercms.search.elasticsearch.impl.ElasticsearchServiceImpl.doIndex(ElasticsearchServiceImpl.java:208)
at org.craftercms.search.elasticsearch.impl.ElasticsearchServiceImpl.index(ElasticsearchServiceImpl.java:195)
at org.craftercms.search.elasticsearch.impl.ElasticsearchServiceImpl.index(ElasticsearchServiceImpl.java:228)
at org.craftercms.search.elasticsearch.batch.ElasticsearchIndexingUtils.doUpdate(ElasticsearchIndexingUtils.java:66)
... 15 more
Caused by: org.craftercms.search.elasticsearch.exception.ElasticsearchException: [**] Error deleting document /*/*/*/**.xml
at org.craftercms.search.elasticsearch.impl.ElasticsearchServiceImpl.doDelete(ElasticsearchServiceImpl.java:279)
at org.craftercms.search.elasticsearch.impl.ElasticsearchServiceImpl.doIndex(ElasticsearchServiceImpl.java:204)
... 18 more
Caused by: ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=cluster_block_exception, reason=blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];]]
at org.elasticsearch.rest.BytesRestResponse.errorFromXContent(BytesRestResponse.java:177)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:2050)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseResponseException(RestHighLevelClient.java:2026)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1775)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1732)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1694)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.delete(RestHighLevelClient.java:1042)
at org.craftercms.search.elasticsearch.impl.ElasticsearchServiceImpl.doDelete(ElasticsearchServiceImpl.java:277)
... 19 more
Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [DELETE], host [http://localhost:9202], URI [/*/*/*/*?timeout=1m], status line [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"cluster_block_exception","reason":"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];"}],"type":"cluster_block_exception","reason":"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];"},"status":403}
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$SyncResponseListener.get(RestClient.java:929)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:229)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1762)
... 23 more
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [DELETE], host [http://localhost:9202], URI [/*/*/*/*?timeout=1m], status line [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"cluster_block_exception","reason":"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];"}],"type":"cluster_block_exception","reason":"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];"},"status":403}
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:548)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:533)
at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.completed(BasicFuture.java:122)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.responseCompleted(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:181)
at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.processResponse(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:448)
at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.inputReady(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:338)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:265)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
... 1 more

I've looked, this may be caused by low disk space or elastic search configuration and index settings, but I'm only using 10% space and read-only mode is already not set for the entire cluster. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

This seems similar to https://groups.google.com/g/craftercms/c/TQ0qL6t4Irw

At a high level, CrafterCMS cannot *write* to the Elasticsearch index. Consider investigating the Elasticsearch configuration/setup to understand better why it's doing that.